# SONOS - rateItem - Not triggering "Operation failed"

Tags: python-2.7, soap, sonos, pysimplesoap

Clicking on either of the rating buttons on my SONOS app causes an "Operation failed" error to appear and I don't know why. Everything else about the app works as expected except for that.

Here is the code for my rate item function. I'm using the pysimplesoap module.

```
def rateItem(id, rating, device, householdId, loginToken):
    # rating =
    # Unrated track -> rating = 1 (good) | rating = 0 (bad)
    # Track has thumbs up  -> rating = 3 (good) | rating = 2 (bad)
    # Track has thumbs down -> rating = 5 (good) | rating = 6 (bad)
    user_record = SonosUserRecord.collection.find_one({"loginToken": loginToken})
    user = get_user_from_username(username=user_record["username"])

    now = datetime.utcnow()
    SonosUserRecord.collection.update({"loginToken": loginToken}, {"$set": {"last_update": now}})
    #rateItemResponse = {"shouldSkip": "false"}
    if rating == 1 or rating == 5:
        print "Rated positive"
        # Rated positive
        rating_value = 5
        toid = id.split(":")[1]
        rating = MongoTrackRating(user, toid)
        rating.set_rating(int(rating_value))
        MongoTrackRatingAggregate.update_track_rating_aggregate(toid, int(rating_value))
    if rating == 0 or rating == 2:
        print "Rated negative"
        # Rated negative
        #rateItemResponse["shouldSkip"] = "true"
        rating_value = 1
        toid = id.split(":")[1]
        rating = MongoTrackRating(user, toid)
        rating.set_rating(int(rating_value))
        MongoTrackRatingAggregate.update_track_rating_aggregate(toid, int(rating_value))
    return rateItemResponse
```

And then I register it.

```
dispatcher.register_function('rateItem', rateItem,
    returns={"rateItemResult": list},
    args={"id": str, "rating": int, 'device':str, 'householdId':str, 'loginToken': str})
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please add the SOAP envelope you return in the `rateItemResponse` by capturing the response with Wireshark or something similar. From the code above, it is possible you're returning an empty envelope.

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion to use Wireshark. I was able to figure out the cause. Apparently my update_track_rating_aggregate method wasn't taking in the right amount of params. Fixed that and the error went away!